# Javascript struct function that takes an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript Noob calling for duty!

I would like to write the code for the following:

```
var p1 = new LatLon(userLat, userLon);                                                    
var p2 = new LatLon(destLat, destLon);  
var dist = p1.distanceTo(p2);
```

which means I need to create a Javascript struct of sorts that will create a position and then also be able to take a second position as an argument. I ***DO NOT need the code to calculate the distance***. I just need to figure out how to create the object and allow it to accept the arguments. Here is my pseudo code/ failed attempt:

```
function LatLon(userLat, userLon) {
    var pos = {
      'lat': userLat, 'lon': userLon, 'distanceTo': distanceBetweenTwoPos(pos, pos2);
    }
    return pos;
}

function distanceBetweenTwoPos(pos, pos2){
    // here I will do my own calculations. 
}
```

Any help on getting something similar to the above, yet functional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the typical prototypal inheritance approach, it could look like this.

```
function LatLon(userLat, userLon) {
    this.lat = userLat;
    this.lon = userLon;
}

LatLon.prototype.distanceTo = function(pos2){
    console.log(this.lat, pos2.lat);
    console.log(this.lon, pos2.lon);
    // return the result
}
```

Inside the `LatLon` constructor, because you're calling it with `new`, `this` is a reference to the object being constructed, `return` statement is needed; it'll return the new object.

Inside `distanceTo`, `this` will be a reference to the object that called the method, so in your code, it would be a reference to the `p1` object.

And of course `p2` will be passed as an argument.

```
var p1 = new LatLon(userLat, userLon);
var p2 = new LatLon(destLat, destLon);  
var dist = p1.distanceTo(p2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function LatLon(userLat, userLon) {
    this.pos = {
      'lat': userLat,
      'lon': userLon
    }
}

LatLon.prototype.distanceTo = function(pos2){
    return this.pos.lat + pos2.pos.lat;
}

var p1 = new LatLon(1, 2);                                                    
var p2 = new LatLon(3, 4);  
var dist = p1.distanceTo(p2); 

alert(dist);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6NGhY/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function LatLon(userLat, userLon) {
    this.lat=userLat;
    this.lon=userLon;
    this.distanceTo=function(to){ return distanceBetweenTwoPos(this, to);}   

}
```